# Using promises response in calendar function ( which required data from ajax call )

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, promise

Ajax call in promise :

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    jQuery.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo site_url();?>/MyController/ajax_cal',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: "JSON",
            success:function(results) {
                resolve(results); 
                //reject(Error(request.statusText)); // status is not 200 O K, so reject
            }
        });
  });
```

Respose from promise

```
promise.then(function(data) {
      alert(data); // this is working fine BUT i want to use this in calendar function 

 }, function(error) {
    console.log('Promise rejected.');
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

Calander javascript code :

```
<!-- Calander Module starts-->
    var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar({

        console.log(data); /// want to use the data from ajax call on promises 
        events_source: data  , // here 
        view: 'month',
        tmpl_path: '<?php echo base_url();?>asserts/bootstrap_calender/tmpls/',
        tmpl_cache: false,
        day: '2017-02-14',
        onAfterEventsLoad: function(events) {
            if(!events) {
                return;
            }
            var list = $('#eventlist');
            list.html('');

            $.each(events, function(key, val) {
                $(document.createElement('li'))
                    .html('<a href="' + val.url + '">' + val.title + '</a>')
                    .appendTo(list);
            });
        },
        onAfterViewLoad: function(view) {
            $('.page-header h3').text(this.getTitle());
            $('.btn-group button').removeClass('active');
            $('button[data-calendar-view="' + view + '"]').addClass('active');
        },
        classes: {
            months: {
                general: 'label'
            }
        }
}); 
(function($) {
$('.btn-group button[data-calendar-nav]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.click(function() {
            calendar.navigate($this.data('calendar-nav'));
        });
    });

    $('.btn-group button[data-calendar-view]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.click(function() {
            calendar.view($this.data('calendar-view'));
        });
    });

    $('#first_day').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        value = value.length ? parseInt(value) : null;
        calendar.setOptions({first_day: value});
        calendar.view();
    });

    $('#language').change(function(){
        calendar.setLanguage($(this).val());
        calendar.view();
    });

    $('#events-in-modal').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val() : null;
        calendar.setOptions({modal: val});
    });
    $('#format-12-hours').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
        calendar.setOptions({format12: val});
        calendar.view();
    });
    $('#show_wbn').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
        calendar.setOptions({display_week_numbers: val});
        calendar.view();
    });
    $('#show_wb').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
        calendar.setOptions({weekbox: val});
        calendar.view();
    });
    $('#events-modal .modal-header, #events-modal .modal-footer').click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation();
    });
}(jQuery));  
<!-- Calander Module ends-->
```

i have want to get the dynamic data (json format ) in "calendar events_source field" . i have use a ajax call but i came to know that the variable are inaccessible outside the ajax call . i  than use promises than i was successfully to alert the variable outside the ajax call But i am still unable to access it in the "calendar events_source field" . i don't know what is wrong and how i can use it .

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to create your calendar element after you have data (in then block). I would probably do it so that I build UI then trigger fetching and in then() function I would call *onAfterEventsLoad* with the received events since it seems to build the the calendar.

Comment: I have tried  the same . i have created the calendar element in the promises . but its not working .

Comment: So what kind of erro/problem you're facing ?

Comment: when i place the calendar element in the "then" block , the calendar element don't execute . else when place outside the "then" block the dynamic data of calendar (ajax output) don't work but the calendar  work .

Comment: I am getting calendar function not found , but it works well with some static content outside the ajax call (BUT i need some dynamic data from my controller )